# Why TextElemt class is not derived from Control class?

Tags: c#, wpf, block, paragraph

Consider this Xaml:

```
<RichTextBox>
<Document>
   <Paragraph> 
       <Run Text="FirstWord " />
       <Run Text="SecondWord"/>
   </Paragraph >
   <Paragraph>  
       <Run Text="FirstWord " />
       <Run Text="SecondWord"/>
   </Paragraph >
 </Document>
</RichTextBox >
```

Now, assume that for some reasons I use something like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation = "Vertical">
   <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">  // as a Paragraph
       <TextBlock Text="FirstWord " />
       <TextBlock Text="SecondWord"/>
   </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">  // another Paragraph
       <TextBlock Text="FirstWord " />
       <TextBlock Text="SecondWord"/>
   </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

A [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or a [Paragraph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.paragraph%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or other [TextElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)s are not Controls and therefore there is no `ArrangeOverride` or `MesureOverride` methods for them. My question is why they are not controls? is it because of performance issues or there is not much difference between measuring size, arranging and rendering of a `TextElement` and a `Control`? In other words, what is the benefits of the first Xaml over the second one (apart from its appearance)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They are not controls because they are not separate from the rest of the document. What you are setting inside the document are not child controls, but the content of the document. The rendering is done completely inside the RichTextBox.

The main difference between first and second example is that RichTextBox allows you to create flowing text with parts of text having different formatting. While it is possible to do it by using normal TextBlocks, it would be hard to fine-tune for things like line-breaks and dynamic resizing.